# Multiple plots in one figure in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am new to python and am trying to plot multiple lines in the same figure using matplotlib.
The value of my Y-axis is stored in a dictionary and I make corresponding values in X-axis in the following code

My code is like this:

```
for i in range(len(ID)):
AxisY= PlotPoints[ID[i]]
if len(AxisY)> 5:
    AxisX= [len(AxisY)]
    for i in range(1,len(AxisY)):
        AxisX.append(AxisX[i-1]-1)
    plt.plot(AxisX,AxisY)
    plt.xlabel('Lead Time (in days)')
    plt.ylabel('Proportation of Events Scheduled')
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.invert_xaxis()
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()
    ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
    plt.show()
```

But I am getting separate figures with a single plot one by one. Can anybody help me figure out what is wrong with my code? Why can't I produce multiple-line plotting? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

This is very simple to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(<X AXIS VALUES HERE>, <Y AXIS VALUES HERE>, 'line type', label='label here')
plt.plot(<X AXIS VALUES HERE>, <Y AXIS VALUES HERE>, 'line type', label='label here')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

You can keep adding `plt.plot` as many times as you like. As for `line type`, you need to first specify the color. So for blue, it's `b`.  And for a normal line it's `-`.  An example would be:

```
plt.plot(total_lengths, sort_times_heap, 'b-', label="Heap")
```

Comment: You can get more information from here -> http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: @liang, you must include the legend. I've edited the answer so that the labels show as well.

Answer (score 19):

Since I don't have a high enough reputation to comment I'll answer liang question on Feb 20 at 10:01 as an answer to the original question.

In order for the for the line labels to show you need to add plt.legend to your code.
to build on the previous example above that also includes title, ylabel and xlabel:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(<X AXIS VALUES HERE>, <Y AXIS VALUES HERE>, 'line type', label='label here')
plt.plot(<X AXIS VALUES HERE>, <Y AXIS VALUES HERE>, 'line type', label='label here')
plt.title('title')
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT**: I just realised after reading your question again, that i did not answer your question. You want to enter multiple lines in the same plot. However, I'll leave it be, because this served me very well multiple times. I hope you find usefull someday

I found this a while back when learning python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure() 
# create figure window

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(a, b)
# Creates grid 'gs' of a rows and b columns 


ax = plt.subplot(gs[x, y])
# Adds subplot 'ax' in grid 'gs' at position [x,y]


ax.set_ylabel('Foo') #Add y-axis label 'Foo' to graph 'ax' (xlabel for x-axis)


fig.add_subplot(ax) #add 'ax' to figure
```

you can make different sizes in one figure as well, use slices in that case:

```
 gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 3)
 ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,:]) # row 0 (top) spans all(3) columns
```

consult the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) for more help and examples. This little bit i typed up for myself once, and is very much based/copied from the docs as well. Hope it helps... I remember it being a pain in the #$% to get acquainted with the slice notation for the different sized plots in one figure. After that i think it's very simple :)

Answer (score 2):

If you work with Pandas it's very easy to do. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [2, 2, 2]})
df.plot(kind='line')
```

[image]

See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)