# 1D function over 2D histogram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I use matplotlib to plot some data in the form of 2D histogram. Typical output of my script looks like this:

[image: Histogram]

The relevant part of the script is here:

```
xbins = 10**np.linspace(-3, 0, 100)
ybins = 10**np.linspace(-3, 0, 100)
counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x1val, x2val, bins=(xbins, ybins))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mesh = ax.pcolormesh(xbins, ybins, counts)#, norm=LogNorm())
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('$x_1$')
plt.ylabel('$x_2$')
plt.title(title)
plt.colorbar(mesh)
```

Where `x1val` and `x2val` are lists filled with data I would like to plot simply a white colored curve defined by some simple `function x2 = f(x1)` over my histogram. Is this possible somehow?

Best,
Radek

Comment: Why wouldn't `plot(x1, x2)` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple plot in one figure in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254472/multiple-plot-in-one-figure-in-python)