# Plot multiple lines on matplotlib graph for time series plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to have a time series plot with years on the x axis and counties/ unemployment rate on the y axis.

The problem is similar to the one suggested duplicate and that is the method I would like to use. The primary difference is that I cannot figure out how to wrangle the data correctly.

The data appears as such

```
name  employment_2007  employment_2008  employment_2009
Napa              200              230              215
Lake              140              130              150
```

---

[Sample of what I'm going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJvwq.png)

[screenshot of code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPYaa.png)

Note in the image I've isolated out one county to make the problem simpler, I plan to add all the counties once I've worked this out.

This is probably more of a data transformation problem, so I should note I'm using a Pandas dataframe to store everything.

Comment: And what have you tried to solve this and why it does not work for you?

Comment: I've tried making two arrays and plotting those

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple plot in one figure in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254472/multiple-plot-in-one-figure-in-python)

Comment: Please add code to your post, dont add this as a comment

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in the following steps:

1. Extract year string from column labels
2. Convert the year string to a date time
3. Plot on same axis by iterating over a groupby object.

Something like:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""name, employment_2007, employment_2008, employment_2016
Napa, 200, 230,215
Lake, 140, 130,150"""),sep=',',index_col=['name'])


#Get year string and convert to date time
df = df.unstack().reset_index()
df['Year'] = df['level_0'].str.split('_').apply(lambda x: x[1])        
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'],format='%Y')

#Get Rid of extra columns and rename series to plot
df = df[['name',0,'TimeStamp']]
df = df.rename(columns={0:'Employment'})
fig,ax= plt.subplots()
for n, group in df.groupby('name'):
    group.plot(x='TimeStamp',y='Employment', ax=ax,label=n)
```

Which produces a plot like:

[image]