# How to add color in plot, python mode [Syntaxiserror]

Tags: python, plot

I'm trying to plot this :

```
plot((1,(x,-2,20), color='green'), (log(x),(x,-2,20), color='red'))
```

in python, but I recieved an error of syntaxis. I already search about how to change the color, but it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance
V

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Comment: sure, here it is .........
File "<ipython-input-33-0bd820d72a7d>", line 1
    plot((1,(x,-2,20), color='green'), (log(x),(x,-2,20), color='red'))
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: the ^, is right below the = sign

Comment: Try run plot function for each plot you have, like this plot(1, (x,-2,20), color='green') and... error is because you create tuple in wrong syntax

Comment: The thing is I want the 2 plots in the same graphic..

Comment: This question can help you with that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254472/multiple-plot-in-one-figure-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Since you presumably are a beginner to `matplotlib`, I would give you a working solution which plots two curves in the same figure. You can modify the values of `x` as per your desired input. Feel free to ask me more in the comments section if you have more doubts.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()

x = np.linspace(1, 20, 100)
y1 = np.log10(x)
y2 = np.ones(100)

plt.plot(x, y1, color='red', label=r'$y=\log(x)$')
plt.plot(x, y2, color='green', label=r'$y=1$')
plt.xlabel('$x$-values', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('$y$-values', fontsize=18)
plt.legend(fontsize=18)
```

**Output**

[image]