# How to plot graph from my input relative with CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot graph to compare cases each countries where I input by string. I import data from [here](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv)

Here's an example of what I'm expecting:

[image: plot]

From that pic. I input N = 3 for range of countries to input. And I input name of each countries step by step. From now. If I want to plot the graph by which countries I was input to compare number of cases in one graph how can I do?

Here is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read file
dfi = pd.read_csv('time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv', sep=',')
df = dfi.drop(['Province/State','Lat','Long'], axis=1)
df

#sum all the cases of each province/State to 1 row.
df_gr = df.groupby('Country/Region').sum()

time = df_gr.columns.tolist()
df_gr.columns = pd.to_datetime(time)
df_gr.reset_index(inplace = True)

countriesx = df_gr['Country/Region'].unique() #keep each country into list.
countries_list = [x for x in countriesx] #clean the data.

df = df_gr.T
new_header = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = new_header

#input the number of countries to compare.
while True:
   N = int(input('The number of countries to compare: '))
   if N < 1 or N > 185:
      print('The value must between1 and 185. Try again.\n')
      continue
   else:
      print('Correct inout.\n')
      break

#input name of countries to compare.
cnt = len(countries_list)
choose = [] #For the name of each countries.

for i in range(N):
   print(f'Country {i+1} of {N}')
      while True:
         my_countries = input('Enter the full country name: ')
         my_countries = my_countries.capitalize()
         countries_list.append(my_countries)

         set_checker = set(countries_list)

      if len(set_checker) == cnt:
         print(f'Country {i+1} confirmed as \'{my_countries}\'.\n')
         choose.append(my_countries)
         break
      else:
         print(f'There is no country named \'{my_countries}\'. Try again\n')
         countries_list.remove(my_countries)
         continue
```

This that I tried.

Comment: Check this: multiple plot in one figure in Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254472/multiple-plot-in-one-figure-in-python]

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I can solved this problem by your help.

Answer (score 0):

Now I can solve my problem. If I want to plot graph by each string in the list, I can do like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(#file.csv)

countries = ['Italy','Japan','Germany']

for i in countries:
   plt.plot(df[i]) #This is data from CSV file

plt.show()
```