# how to execute different block of code in a button function?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

```
#use of button
plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes([0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1])
gen = Button(ax, label='generator')
def generator(event):
  a.cla()
  a.hist(x)
  b.cla()
  b.hist(y)
gen.on_clicked(generator)
plt.show()
```

The problem is when I click the 'gen' button, only the `a` histogram is being plotted but the `b` histogram is not being plotted. If I flip the sequence then the `b` histogram is plotted and the `a` histogram is then ignored. I cannot seem to figure it out. how to work different block of code in the function definition for button on_clicked method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple plot in one figure in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254472/multiple-plot-in-one-figure-in-python)

Comment: no, i think i was not clear with my question. Problem is I am using matplotlib button widget and i  have created two subplot in figure. But when i click the button only a axes is being plotted and somehow b is being ignored even though they are in the same function for on_clicked method of button